# HTML to pdf broken image

Tags: html, image, pdf, power-automate

i'm having a broken image when converting HTML to PDF file.
I'm using power automate to do it.

I have the image in the same folder than the template and I don't see why it is hapenning.

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Tatiana

---

Code HTML:

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border:none;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 15.4181%; padding: 0cm 5.4pt; height: 52.55pt; vertical-align: middle;">
            <p style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:0cm;line-height:105%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><span style='font-size:15px;line-height:105%;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><img src="dataUri(logo.jpg)" alt="logo" width="77px"></span><br></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 84.4077%; padding: 0cm 5.4pt; height: 52.55pt; vertical-align: middle;">
            <p style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:0cm;line-height:105%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><strong><span style='font-size:21px;line-height:105%;font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif;color:#1F4E79;'>Renault CACIA: Enquête de satisfation Client</span></strong></p>
            <p style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom:0cm;margin-left:0cm;line-height:105%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;'><em><span style='font-size:19px;line-height:105%;font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif;color:#1F4E79;'>Renault CACIA: Customer satisfation Survey</span></em>&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hey @Tatiana, can you please show us part of your HTML code? Have you included `datauri(image)` on image tag?

Comment: @NcXNaV, see the edit above.
Thank you.

Comment: Try quotes dataUri('logo.jpg') or is there a more direct path for dataUri(logo.jpg)  like dataUri('https://somelocation.comlogo.jpg')

Comment: @Cameron, it didn't work too :(
Thank you.

Comment: @KJ, it worked, appears a red dot.